# Apache - Running Long Running Processes In Background

Tags: python, apache, background-process

Before you go any further, I am currently working in a very restricted environment.  Installing additional dll's/exe's, and other admin like activities are frustratingly difficult.  I am fully aware that some of the methodology described in this post is far from best practice...

I would like to start a long running background process that start/stops with Apache.  I have a cgi enabled python script that takes as input all of the parameters necessary to run a complex "job".  It is not feasible to run this job in the cgi script itself - because a)cgi is already slow to begin with and b)multiple simultaneous requests would definitely cause trouble.  The cgi script will do nothing more than enter the parameters into a "jobs" database.

Normally, I would set something up like MSMQ in conjunction with a Windows Service.  I would have a web service add a job to the queue, and the windows service would be polling the queue at some standard interval - processing jobs in sequence...

How could I accomplish the same in Apache?  I can easily enough create a python script to serve as the background job processor.  My questions are:

1. how do I start it process up with, leave it running with, and stop with Apache?
2. how can i monitor the process - make sure stays alive with Apache?

Any tips or insight welcome.

Note.  OS is Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a pretty hacky solution for anyone looking to do something similar.

1. Set up a windows scheduled task that does that background processing.  set it to run once a day or whatever interval you want (it is irrelevant, as you'll see in next steps)
2. In the Settings tab of the Scheduled Task - make sure the "Allow task to be run on demand" option is checked.  Also, under the "If the task is already running..." text, make sure the Do not start a new instance option in selected.

Then, from the cgi script - it is possible to invoke the scheduled task from the command line(subprocess module) see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721884.aspx).  With the options set above - if the task is already running - any subsequent run on demands are ignored.